# What is the unit of molar density?

Tags: units

I'm reading *Unit operations of Chemical Engineering*, 5th edition by Warren McCabe.

They defined the "molar density $\rho_{M}$" as $\ce{\rho_{M}=\frac{n}{V}}$. The parameters $n$ and $V$ are the number of moles and volume as usual (they are indicated in the summary table of all the symbols at the end of the chapter). To my understanding, $\rho_{M}$ indicates how many moles of a molecule are there in a volume unit and its unit should be something like $\ce{mol/m^3}$ or $\ce{mol/cm^3}$.
[[image: The definition of <span class=]$\rho_{M}$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rklY4.png)

However, the unit of $\rho_{M}$ in that table is $\ce{kg\cdot mol/m^3}$. Why is there the presence of mass?
[image: The symbols with explanation at the end of the chapter]

Comment: kg mol is the way some engineering texts refer to kmol (1000 mol). g mol is the same as mol. lb mol is useful if you're converting from mol to lb, for example the molar mass of water is 18 g/mol or 18 lb/lbmol. It is defintely confusing in a way since you can read "kg times mol", which is nonsense, though it is less confusing if you write it altogether: kgmol instead of kg mol.

Comment: :) Thanks for your help. Now it makes a lot of sense. It was really confusing